# Stacked Barplot of a Dataframe in R (colors for categories, not counts)

Tags: r, ggplot2

This should not be so complicated! The question of plotting a dataframe in R seems to get asked over and over, but not a single solution works for me. I'm trying to create a simple stacked barplot from this dataframe:

```
category     a    b
foo          2    0
bar          1    1
spam         0    1
```

`a` and `b` should be the x-axis labels, and `foo, bar, spam` the stacked colors in the bar.

The closest I've gotten is:

```
library(reshape2)

ggplot(melt(df), aes(variable, value)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', aes(fill=value))
```

This gives me the column names on the x-axis, but stacked colored bars for the total count of each category instead of stacked colors, one each for `foo, bar, spam`.

I'm not attached to any particular method, I just want a stacked barplot from my dataframe.

This is the file from dput:

```
structure(list(category = c("bar", "foo", "spam"), a = c(1L, 
2L, 0L), b = c(1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("category", "a", "b"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(category = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), b = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("category", "a", "b")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

The above works, it was created in (I thought) the exact same way as the much larger df below:

```
structure(list(tissue = c("Adipose_Subcutaneous", "Adipose_Visceral_Omentum", 
"Adrenal_Gland", "Artery_Aorta", "Artery_Coronary", "Artery_Tibial", 
"Brain_Amygdala", "Brain_Anterior_cingulate_cortex_BA24", "Brain_Caudate_basal_ganglia", 
"Brain_Cerebellar_Hemisphere", "Brain_Cerebellum", "Brain_Cortex", 
"Brain_Frontal_Cortex_BA9", "Brain_Hippocampus", "Brain_Hypothalamus", 
"Brain_Nucleus_accumbens_basal_ganglia", "Brain_Putamen_basal_ganglia", 
"Brain_Spinal_cord_cervical_c-1", "Brain_Substantia_nigra", "Breast_Mammary_Tissue", 
"Cells_EBV-transformed_lymphocytes", "Cells_Transformed_fibroblasts", 
"Colon_Sigmoid", "Colon_Transverse", "Esophagus_Gastroesophageal_Junction", 
"Esophagus_Mucosa", "Esophagus_Muscularis", "Heart_Atrial_Appendage", 
"Heart_Left_Ventricle", "Liver", "Lung", "Minor_Salivary_Gland", 
"Muscle_Skeletal", "Nerve_Tibial", "Ovary", "Pancreas", "Pituitary", 
"Prostate", "Skin_Not_Sun_Exposed_Suprapubic", "Skin_Sun_Exposed_Lower_leg", 
"Small_Intestine_Terminal_Ileum", "Spleen", "Stomach", "Testis", 
"Thyroid", "Uterus", "Vagina", "Whole_Blood"), BEB = c(8L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CDX = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    CEU = c(8L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    1L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 2L), CHB = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CLM = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 11L, 
    0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), FIN = c(9L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
    4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 
    12L, 15L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 15L, 10L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 
    8L, 14L, 0L, 8L, 2L, 17L, 13L, 1L, 0L, 2L), GBR = c(15L, 
    11L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 20L, 18L, 8L, 6L, 
    2L, 13L, 0L, 22L, 21L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 9L, 20L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 
    9L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 10L), GIH = c(2L, 51L, 0L, 59L, 0L, 5L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 
    1L, 53L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 97L, 53L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 24L, 1L, 90L, 
    58L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 54L, 77L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 54L, 20L, 0L, 
    1L, 17L), IBS = c(7L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    11L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 10L), JPT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L
    ), KHV = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), MXL = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), PEL = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
    0L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), PJL = c(5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 0L, 1L), PUR = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
    STU = c(17L, 28L, 9L, 22L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 4L, 12L, 
    2L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 6L, 26L, 10L, 9L, 
    26L, 36L, 23L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 0L, 62L, 18L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 9L, 
    44L, 57L, 0L, 18L, 1L, 0L, 21L, 9L, 0L, 9L), TSI = c(13L, 
    11L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 15L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 15L, 18L, 10L, 10L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 
    13L, 0L, 14L, 4L, 19L, 22L, 8L, 14L, 9L, 4L, 13L, 21L, 4L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 21L, 6L, 4L, 13L), Category = c("1", "2", "3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
    "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
    "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", 
    "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", 
    "45", "46", "47", "48")), .Names = c("tissue", "BEB", "CDX", 
"CEU", "CHB", "CLM", "FIN", "GBR", "GIH", "IBS", "JPT", "KHV", 
"MXL", "PEL", "PJL", "PUR", "STU", "TSI", "Category"), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(tissue = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), BEB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), CDX = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), CEU = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), CHB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), CLM = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), FIN = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), GBR = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), GIH = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), IBS = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), JPT = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), KHV = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), MXL = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), PEL = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), PJL = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), PUR = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), STU = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), TSI = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("tissue", "BEB", "CDX", "CEU", "CHB", 
"CLM", "FIN", "GBR", "GIH", "IBS", "JPT", "KHV", "MXL", "PEL", 
"PJL", "PUR", "STU", "TSI")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I did try using 'tissue' instead of 'category' in both the `fill=` and `aes(df,`. It's still giving me bars of one color and a legend that just says 'tissue'.

Located the problem!! I went back to an earlier try, after trying the `aes(fill=` solution, I thought it was wrong because it was just a giant legend. Turns out the legend was so giant it clustered my graph off to the side so it wasn't visible.

Comment: I think you're mixing stacked and dodge position: try `position = "dodge"` and `fill = category`.

Comment: `aes(fill = category)` is all it takes. `geom_col` also makes life a bit easier than `geom_bar`.

Comment: I've tried putting the aes(fill = category) arguments in both ggplot() and geom_col(), both give me the error `object 'category' not found`

Comment: Try `melt(df, "category")`

Comment: `Error: id variables not found in data: category` :/

Comment: Add original data to your question using `dput` function.

Comment: Your example data indicates that `category` is a data frame column name. The error indicates that it isn't. We need to see how the data frame was made.

Comment: I note in your second example data frame that `Category` has an upper-case `C`. R variable names are case-sensitive: `aes(fill = Category)`. I also note that there are many categories, too many to distinguish by colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I suggest a different approach, based on two observations:

- there are far too many categories (48 tissues) to distinguish by fill colour
- stacking suggests that each tissue as a proportion of the total has some relevance, which I doubt in this case given the very different tissues

So how about plotting tissue against variable (population I assume) and colouring the tiles by value. I use `df1` for the data frame name.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -tissue, -Category) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(tissue, variable)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
    scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint = 50) + 
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Heatmap is probably the best approach with a given data. Also, forgot to add  `theme_classic` or similar one :-)

Comment: Oh wow thank you!! I was struggling to find a good data visualization, and this works much better!

Comment: @neilfws Looking through your profile it seems like you know what you're doing. :) Do you have any recommendations for data visualization resources for data scientists? I'm thinking maybe some kind of R cookbook with lots of examples of different ways to visualize biological data.

Comment: Nothing in particular, I think experience is the best teacher :) You should probably look at [R for data science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) and maybe the [ggplot2 book](http://ggplot2.org/book/). Closest thing to a cookbook is [this for ggplot2](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/). For biology it's worth getting to grips with [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/).